# is Recursive query supported in Greenplum

Tags: greenplum, connect-by

There is one query in oracle which is using `CONNECT BY`,
 my requirement is i need to migrate it to Greenplum Sql

I found n tried with recursive class, but getting below error

> ********** Error **********
>   ERROR: RECURSIVE option in WITH clause is not supported
>   SQL state: 0AM00

I didn't get any resolution for below, also let me know/post any query or example where you used with recursive class

Requirement is

I have a table like :

```
SKey KPI ParentKPI
1 A 0
2 B 1
3 C 2
4 D 3
5 E 4
```

Need output like below using something similar to Oracle’s `connect by`:

```
1 : A
2 : A, B
3 : A, B, C
4 : A, B, C, D
5 : A, B, C, D, E
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Greenplum is based on Postgres 8.2 which did no have recursive queries. So I guess you are out of luck. Back in the days I think there was a additional module called "connectby" (or something similar) which would provide a function that retrieved the information recursively.

Comment: Thanks, Will it work if i upgrade the version of postgres, currently in my environment it is 8.2.15

Comment: As I said: recursive queries where introduced in Postgres with V8.4 so yes if you switch from Greenplum to a current Postgres version you will get the ability to run recursive queries